# Android APK failed to upload to play store Strange issue

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I am having this issue for two years. I can't be able to upload android APK to play store. The app is written in phonegape and I compile the Signed APK from android studio.
What I am having error is:

```
Your APK's version code needs to be higher than 100008.
```

Facts:

- There are nothing like 100008 word or number in whole project.
- I changed All version codes to 100009, still same error

Comment: You've changed the versionCode in `config.xml`? http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_basics.md.html

Comment: Yes I did that already. Many times. @KenWolf

Comment: If you are building through Android Studio you might have to change the VersionCode in Gradle settings...have you tried that? I think config.xml is only for builds through PhoneGap Build?

Comment: I changed in gradle as well

Comment: But in gradle there is not info regarding version

Comment: Add it to Gradle `defaultConfig {
           minSdkVersion XX
           targetSdkVersion YY
           versionCode 100009
           versionName "Your Version Name"
       }`

Comment: Thank you @KenWolf, this actually worked like a charm. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Studio uses Gradle to build your projects.

To increment the android version code using Gradle add the following to `build.gradle` in your `app` module:

```
defaultConfig { 
    minSdkVersion XX 
    targetSdkVersion YY 
    versionCode 100009 
    versionName "Your Version Name" 
}
```

Replacing where necessary. The key part is the versionCode must be higher than what is already on the store.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to decompile your apk and check a version in the result manifest file.
You may use this tool http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/

Hope it helps!

I guess you have read this already: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning.html

Comment: What to do with the decompiler?

Comment: 1. Download and install it from there http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/install/

2. Run like this `apktool d yourapkfile.apk`

3. Check results in apktool.yml file, there will be `versionInfo:
  versionCode: 'yourapkversioncode'
  versionName: 'yourapkversionname'`

Check the fields have correct values.